# SAPUI5 DateTimeInput open by Button

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm using a sap.m.DateTimeInput in my XML View. When the input is clicked the DatePicker Popup is opened. Now I want to add a Button beside the DateTimeInput, and let open the Date popup on button click. DateTimeInput provides no method to open the Popup as far as i know. I'using SAPUI5 version 1.28. 
How can i achieve this ? 
I'm a little bit lost in Borwser Events, handlers and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the Date Picker control. I think that this control is what you want.

[Date Picker Control](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/sample/sap.m.sample.DatePicker/preview)